# In Hugo Academic, how to fix "Error in user YAML: mapping values are not allowed". Hyperlinks problem

Tags: github, yaml

I'm working in Hugo Academic, and I'm trying to write following code in a blo

```
block: Accomplishments
- content:
    items:
    - certificate_url: 
      date_end: ''
      date_start: '2023-06-01'
      description: Visiting professor in following universities<br />- June 2023: [LinKóping University](https://liu.se/en)<br />- November 2019: [University of Sheffield](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/) <br />
```

However, GitHub shows me back the error "Error in user YAML: mapping values are not allowed". In my head, I would like to get something like this:

Visiting professor in following universities:

- June 2023: [LinKóping University](https://liu.se/en)
- November 2019: [University of Sheffield](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/)

I think it might be due to the hyperlinks, but I don't know how to solve it. Is there a smarter way to do this? Maybe creating subitems or so? Thanks a lot

Comment: From a YAML-only perspective, this isn't valid YAML: Firstly, `block: Accomplishments` makes the value of `block` a scalar, but the subsequent `- content` requires it to be a map, but it can't be both at the same time. Secondly, the value of `description` contains text followed by a colon, a whitespace, and more text (`…June 2023: [LinKóping…` and `November 2019: [University`), so a YAML parser would see this as another mapping attempt, which is not allowed in this context. But I don't know what GitHub/Hugo accept or not, this comment is just based on the [YAML specs](https://yaml.org/spec/).

Comment: ok, thanks, I think that you're right and I should check it from the YAML perspective. How could be corrected the code with this view?

Comment: Here in line 88 lays the example code from the template https://github.com/HugoBlox/theme-academic-cv/edit/main/content/_index.md

Comment: The linked file is valid YAML. In particular, line 88 starts a new sequence item (denoted by the `-`) which itself is a map (because some key-value pairs follow). That map's first item (still in line 88) is `block: accomplishments`, thus a scalar. The next item starts in line 89 with key `content` (note that there is no `-` before it). Its value is not a scalar (there's nothing after the colon in that line) but a map (note the indentation of the following lines) with keys `title`, `subtitle`, `date_format`, etc. Have a look at the aforementioned YAML specs to understand how YAML is structured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you linked, the expected structure seems to be

```yaml
sections:
- block: Accomplishments
  content:
    items:
    - certificate_url: 
      date_end: ''
      date_start: '2023-06-01'
      description: >-
        Visiting professor in following universities<br
        />- June 2023: [LinKóping University](https://liu.se/en)<br
        />- November 2019: [University of Sheffield](https://www.sheffield.ac.uk/) <br />
```

I used a folded block scalar for the description to avoid parsing parts of it as YAML substructure. The line breaks are optional and solely introduced for readability. I made them within the `<br />` tags because those line breaks get folded into a space character.

You could instead use a double-quoted scalar:

```yaml
      description: "Visiting professor in following universities<br />\
        - June 2023: [LinKóping University](https://liu.se/en)<br />\
        - November 2019: [University of Sheffield]"
```

Both styles allow writing it in a single line, but a line break is required after `>-` before the content.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @flyx. It worked! Is there any way to remove unwanted fields, please? For instance, I would like to omit `certificate_url`. Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know this Hugo Academic tool and therefore cannot answer that. You can try just omitting the fields and if you run into problems, ask a new question.